# GraphhopperWebClient does not recognize the profile in GHRequest

Tags: backend, graphhopper

After creating GHRequest with coordinates, details parameters, etc. and want to send it via GraphhopperWebClient to the server, I get an error that says:

```
The requested profile 'name=car|vehicle=car|weighting=fastest|turnCosts=false|hints={}' does not exist.
Available profiles: [foot, car, bike]]
```

**I am creating GHRequest in this way:**

**(1)** Here I will read parameters and insert informations such as point coordinates, details... in GHRequest:

```
GHRequest ghRequest = getGHRequest(
                param0,
                param1,
                param2
        );
```

**(2)** Then I will create Profile for the GHRequest:

```
Profile profile = new Profile("car")
            .setVehicle("car")
            .setWeighting("false")
            .setTurnCosts(false);
```

**(3)** At the end, I will set GHRequest's profile:

```
ghRequest.setProfile(ghProfile.toString());
```

---

My next step is to use [GraphhopperWebClient](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/tree/master/client-hc) to send the request on my server that has Graphhopper instance running on it:

**(4)** I will create GraphhopperWeb client instance with my server address:

```
GraphHopperWeb client = new GraphHopperWeb("http:baseURL/route");
client.setPostRequest(false);
```

**(5)** I am sending created GHRequest on the server and parseing the response in GHResponse:

```
GHResponse response = client.route(ghRequest);
```

---

I don't need to insert my key because Graphhopper is running on my server and I just need to send a GET request on it and parse the response.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Profiles that can be used must be set up on the server. So I already have `car`, `foot` and `bike` profiles on my server. They already have weighting, turn description, etc parameters. What I needed to do is decide which of the profiles will be used by writing:

```
Profile profile = new Profile(profileName);
```

`String profileName` is the name of the profile I want to use that is already on the server. So in my case I just need to use:

```
Profile profile = new Profile("car");
```

GHRequest will use `car` profile that is already set up on the Graphhopper server instance.